# Python coding mistake. Image recognition. Ending a loop

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a big problem that i cant seem to figure out ... im trying to learn Python but im making a mistake in my coding. Can you teach me what im doing wrong ?

Im trying to look for an image on the entire screen and if the script finds it, it prints "I can see it" otherwise if it does not see it, it prints "I am unable to see it".

I want that ^ to run on a loop and when i press a key, i want the whole thing to pause untill i press that key again. How can i do this ?

```
import sys
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
from threading import Thread

def stoper():
    a = keyboard.read_key()
    if a == "p":
        print('Program has stopped...')
        exit()
    else:
        print("Wrong key champ !")
        return
def starter():
    while True:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence =.5) != None:
            print("I can see it")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            print("I am unable to see it")
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = stoper).start()
    Thread(target = starter).start()
```

Comment: duplicate by same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027970/how-to-close-a-while-true-loop-instantly-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close a while True loop instantly Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027970/how-to-close-a-while-true-loop-instantly-python)